# Magento 2 Checkout page speed slow

Tags: magento2

i am using magento 2 with porto theme. and i am facing issue in checkout page my checkout load speed very slow and my website other pages load speed 2 sec per page also i have run website production mode but still slow speed on checkout page 7 to 10 sec  . please help me anyone

Comment: Without veryfying the store it is difficult to suggest the fix. Try enabling the profiler and check the bottleneck.

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV  please tell me how to enable profiler or check bottleneck

Comment: please check these links on how to enable profiler. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html, https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-enabledisable-magento-2-profiler/, otherwise you can use Amasty module also - https://github.com/mirasvit/module-profiler. This Video can help you understand how to use it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnjfuCIJQ-I

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do in your situation:

1. Turn off all 3rd-party modules and check the speed. If the site becomes significantly faster - one of the plugins is the issue.
2. Switch to a default luma theme and check the speed. If it makes the checkout faster - you have some poorly coded theme files.

Try a code profiler, New Relic or Tideways and see what code block is slow.